# What are the additional transistors used for in this hex inverter?

Tags: transistors, schematics, 7400

I'm learning about electronics and was studying the SN7404 hex inverter schematic when I saw this:

[image]

I naively expected just a single transistor (the one in the bottom right) and the input at the base of that transistor to give the inverted input at Output Y.

Yet there are 3 other transistors, a bunch of resistors and a couple of diodes in addition.

Can someone here help to explain what the purposes of these are and the reason for the resistor values?

Source datasheet here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls04-sp.pdf

Comment: https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics-lab-27

Comment: What you are describing would only be able to pull low and would not be able to give a low impedance output when high.

Comment: Also, here is a very good explanation on what happens within the phase-splitting/output driver stages: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/396739/107479

Comment: Hi dim. Thanks for the link, that's a great resource which explains! :)

Comment: By the way, that resistive pullup on the first transistor's base is one cause of high timing jitter in TTL gates. In fact, LPSTTL uses 10X higher Rpullup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic TTL gate.

To ensure that all TTL devices present the same load, the input is always a transistor with the emitter at the actual input (multi-input devices have multiple input emitters).

The next transistor is a drive stage and the output is a [totem-pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_output) stage which can both source (output high) and sink (output low) current.

The output current in the high and low states are different (and for a single fan out match the input current for TTL devices).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With the above overview, it gave me the right direction to look in.